# Best approach for smoothing brick

Tags: walls, brick

I am rebuilding the wall at the front of my house, but the previous (now partially taken down) wall was built *into* the pillar on my neighbours land.

It used to look like this (pillar is 100% on their land, white wall is 100% on mine);

[image]

It currently looks like this;

[image]

What is the best tools/ technique to "sand" the bricks in the pillar, so it resembles a pillar in it's own right? (I then plan to build my new wall adjacent (but separate) to the neighbours pillar).

Some thoughts;

1. Use an angle grinder to sand the brick down. Not sure it's the right tool?
2. Chisel out the "jutting out bricks", and replace them. Not sure how cleanly the bricks will come out?
3. Knock down the pillar, and rebuild it. Seems like a waste, when it's only a few bricks that are the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would have cut the bricks with a masonary saw to give the straight neat line then sorted the mortar lines.

You can still do this to tidy the edges up and use some of the half bricks to fill the gaps and then finish the mortar lines.

One point about the construction was the wall was built and just the pillar part continued upwards leaving the wall surface at its height.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say “masonry saw”, do you mean a masonry handsaw (e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B019ZZV57M ), or a power tool?

Comment: Which one are you prepared to buy or rent? But as pointed out even an angle grinder with a masonary blade will do some of it...

Comment: I’m happy to buy/ rent whatever you suggest. I’m just unsure whether you had a hand saw, or power tool in mind (and/ or whether it’s realistic to expect a hand saw to be able to do the job?). Google returns both results for “masonry saw”.

Comment: Depends on the brick, and on you. Some brick is very soft and cuts easily, some is much harder. Some people are utterly unwilling to use a tool without a motor to cut things, some are not. If it's soft brick and you are willing to use a hand powered saw, it will probably be the most cost effective way. If it's hard brick but the saw has appropriate teeth, it will go slower but still be possible.

Comment: Thanks all. I have a hand saw arriving Friday. Will report back how I get on!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the right angle grinder with a masonry cutting blade. It will be really dusty, and the texture of the cut made by the grinder will look a bit different from the original texture of the brick. It will be better than what you have now...